SVG Gradient is not visible


 <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' version='1.1' id='Livello_1' x='0px' y='0px' viewBox='0 0 150 100' xml:space='preserve'>
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id='gradient1' x1='0' y1='25' x2='0' y2='50' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse'>
            <stop stop-color='#cd62db' offset='0'></stop>
            <stop stop-color='#0c2e89' offset='1'></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polyline style='fill=: url(#gradient1)' fill-opacity='0.1' stroke='#0c2e89' 
         stroke-width='1' points='0 150 0,83 1,84 2,77 3,76 4,79 6,79 7,76 8,77 9,75 10,77 12,79 13,82 14,86 15,90 16,89 18,90 19,96 20,97 21,90 22,93 24,96 25,87 26,96 27,95 28,82 30,82 31,87 32,83 33,90 34,87 36,100 37,95 38,97 39,96 40,91 42,91 43,80 44,73 45,75 46,74 48,83 49,86 50,83 51,74 52,81 54,86 55,75 56,77 57,86 58,84 60,87 61,94 62,93 63,89 64,86 66,86 67,87 68,88 69,88 70,95 150 100 Z'/>
    <text font-family='Segoe UI' font-size='24' x='90' y='20'> 98%</text>
    </svg>



I am trying to apply gradient fill in the area chart but it's not working

Your gradient is not in the same place as your text.

Typo: style='fill=: url(#gradient1)'. Also you have fill-opacity='0.1'

Could you please fix the code and share. Thanks. I have tried the changes as suggested but gradient not applied

@RobertLongson Thanks. I want to apply gradient on Chart area instead of text.

It's not over that either

Like Robert and Exaneta say; you have 2 errors. Remove the fill-opacity and change all gradient x=y values to cover the polyline

I am not sure with the comments. I have removed the 'fill-opacity' from the code.
Can you please elaborate to understand where x=y is required. Please share some sample

y1='25' and y2='50' are incorrect. Adjust the values to cover where you want to have the gradient.

Thanks Robert. LinearGradient is not working for the area under the line. It is not reflecting any colour. I have tried to change the values for y1 and y2 respectively but no luck.
If someone try at your end and share the code would be great help.

The second number in the points attribute is 150. This confuses things because the gradient will end 50 units below the bottom edge of the SVG. Changing that to 100, and making the gradientUnits objectBoundingBox (the default) will make more sense.
I also removed the opacity-fill because it was really hard to see the gradient in the first place.


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 100" style="height: 100vh;">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1"
      gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <stop stop-color="#cd62db" offset="0"/>
      <stop stop-color="#0c2e89" offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <polyline fill="url(#gradient1)" stroke="#0c2e89" stroke-width="1"
    points="0 100 0,83 1,84 2,77 3,76 4,79 6,79 7,76 8,77 9,75 10,77 12,79 13,82 14,86 15,90 16,89 18,90 19,96 20,97 21,90 22,93 24,96 25,87 26,96 27,95 28,82 30,82 31,87 32,83 33,90 34,87 36,100 37,95 38,97 39,96 40,91 42,91 43,80 44,73 45,75 46,74 48,83 49,86 50,83 51,74 52,81 54,86 55,75 56,77 57,86 58,84 60,87 61,94 62,93 63,89 64,86 66,86 67,87 68,88 69,88 70,95 150 100 Z"/>
  <text font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="24" x="90" y="20"> 98%</text>
</svg>




Thanks for your help and well explanation. It works great.
